# Route for getting a review for a book in a MERN-stack book review app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to write a MERN stack app used for reviewing books.

I have 2 MongoDB (Mongoose) schemas: `models/Book.js` and `models/Review.js`, where one Book can have multiple Reviews.

These are my schemas:

**models/Review.js:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let reviewSchema = new Schema(
    {
        text: {
            type: String
        },
        book: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Book'
        }
    }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Review', reviewSchema)
```

**models/Book.js:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let bookSchema = new Schema(
    {
        title: {
            type: String
        },
        detail: {
            type: String
        }
    }, {
        collection: 'books'
    }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Book', bookSchema)
```

How should a route look like if I want to get all data about a single book via this URL: `/book/<book_id_from_mongodb>`?

I can only get Book's data but I don't know how to get all Reviews that belong to that particular book:

**/routes/book.route.js:**

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router();

let bookSchema = require('../models/Book');
let reviewSchema = require('../models/Review');

// Get a single book - HOW SHOULD I MODIFY THIS ROUTE TO GET ALSO ALL REVIEWS FOR THAT BOOK ?
router.route('/book/:id').get((req, res) => {
    bookSchema.findById(req.params.id, (error, data) => {
        if (error) {
            res.status(500).send(err);
        } else {
            res.status(200).json(data)
        }
    })
})
```

I tried this (not working):

```
router.route('/book/:id').get((req, res) => {
    bookSchema.findById(req.params.id, (error, data) => {
        if (error) {
            res.status(500).send(err);
        } else {
            var bookData = data;

            reviewSchema.find({"book": mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)}, (error, data) => {
                if (error) {
                    res.status(500).send(err);
                } else {
                    var reviewData = data;

                    bookData.reviews = reviewData;

                    res.status(200).json(bookData);
                }
            });
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it would be to put a reviews element into your bookSchema and reference the ObjectId of the review.

Then on your get route, use .populate("reviews").exec(your callback).

**Book Schema**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let bookSchema = new Schema(
    {
        title: {
            type: String
        },
        detail: {
            type: String
        }
    }, {
        collection: 'books'
    }, {
        reviews: [
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Review'
        ]
    }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Book', bookSchema)
```

**Route**

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router();

let bookSchema = require('../models/Book');
let reviewSchema = require('../models/Review');

// Get a single book - HOW SHOULD I MODIFY THIS ROUTE TO GET ALSO ALL REVIEWS FOR THAT BOOK ?
router.route('/book/:id').get((req, res) => {
    bookSchema.findById(req.params.id).populate("reviews").exec((error, data) => {
        if (error) {
            res.status(500).send(err);
        } else {
            res.status(200).json(data)
        }
    })
})
```

When creating a review you need to push it to the bookSchema.reviews and then use bookSchema.save() to it.

Let me know if it does not work.

I may have missed something.